# Jquery reset form no erase fields

Tags: jquery, reset

I need erase or empty input fields of form i use this but no works :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
jQuery("#contact_form").get(0).reset()  
});
</script>

<form id="contact_form" name="form" method="post" action="">

<input name="c_name" type="text" title="Insert Personal Name" value="Personal Name" />

</form>
```

The script must erase the content of input text and no show the text Personal name , the case it´s no works and no reset the form

I dont know if exists some error but i think must works

Thank´s , Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reset a form with input value defined by using inline attribute, use `.val()`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ99a/121/)**

```
$("#contact_form input[name=c_name]").val('');
```

Or add a button, and reset form on click event of it.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tZ99a/120/)**

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#contact_form")[0].reset();
});
```

*Note : `reset()` changes the value of input to its inital value (in your case it will reset to Personal Name.*